# Working on local but getting 500 error on vercel in Nextjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, vercel

This is the route.ts

```
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
import PizZip from 'pizzip';
import Docxtemplater from 'docxtemplater';
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export async function POST(req: Request) {
    try {
        const { name, roll_no, batch, experiment, classNo } = await req.json();

        if(!name || !roll_no || !batch || !experiment || !classNo){
            return NextResponse.json({ message: 'Missing Details' }, { status: 400 });
        }

        const content = fs.readFileSync(
            path.resolve('data', `${experiment}.docx`),
            'binary'
        );

        const zip = new PizZip(content);

        const doc = new Docxtemplater(zip, {
            paragraphLoop: true,
            linebreaks: true,
        });

        doc.render({
            name: name,
            roll_no: roll_no,
            experiment: experiment,
            classNo: classNo,
            batch: batch,
        });

        const buf = doc.getZip().generate({
            type: 'nodebuffer',
            compression: 'DEFLATE',
        });

        const fileName = `${name}_${experiment}.docx`;
        const filePathWithName = path.resolve(path.join('data',fileName))

        fs.writeFileSync(filePathWithName, buf);
        const file = await fs.openAsBlob(filePathWithName);
        return new NextResponse(file,{headers:{'Content-Disposition': `attachment; filename=${fileName}`,'Content-Type': 'application/docx'}})
    } catch (error) {
        return NextResponse.json({ message: 'Error generating document' }, { status: 500 });
    }
}

export async function DELETE(req:NextRequest){
    const {doc} = await req.json()
    const filePathWithName = path.resolve(path.join('data',doc))
    fs.unlinkSync(filePathWithName)
    return NextResponse.json('success')
}
```

It works on my laptop fine but when I deploy it on vercel I get 500 internal server error which is different form the catch(error).
Please help...

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqZTn.png)

I tried changing the path.resolve() but it still didn.t work

Comment: can you give us the screenshot of the error  and the log in vercel.

Comment: Click on error screenshot to view it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to fetch from the local API. To fetch to the local API in NextJs13 use `http://yourlocalhost/api/..`

```
const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/download`)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that if your api route is correct and everything works locally on the development server but not on vercel, then it may be because you have to explicitly store the environment variable in the project on vercel if you have connected a database. I had a similar case and that solved the problem directly. So, check whether you have stored the connection string in Vercel for the respective project under environmental variables. I hope this helps..